# How to skip directly to email app AND setType(audio/wav)?

Tags: android

When you intent.setType("message/rfc822") you bypass the intent chooser and head straight to the email app, however, i also need to     intent.setType("audio/wav");

How can I accomplish both??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you intent.setType("message/rfc822") you bypass the intent chooser and head straight to the email app.

You will only see that effct on devices that have a single email client that supports that MIME type. Many devices will have more than one email client (e.g., Gmail and something else), and if they both support that MIME type, a chooser will appear.

> How can I accomplish both??

You don't.

If there is a specific email address you are mailing to, use a `mailto:` `Uri` in an `ACTION_SENDTO` `Intent`, along with your desired MIME type.

If there is no specific email address, then you should not be limiting the user to email. Please allow the user [to share the `audio/wav` file how the user wants](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html), which may or may not be by email.